# Recognize diagonal gestures(swipe) using Hammer.js

Tags: swipe, hammer.js

Is it possible to recognize diagonal swipe using Hammer.js?

I have gone through their documentation but didn't find anything saying about diagonal swiping or pan etc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An object with a lot of info about the gesture is passed to every Hammer.js event callback (as described [here in the API docs](http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#event-object)).

The `eventObject.angle` property is what you are looking for. Its values are between **-180** and **180** (**0** means RIGHT, **-90** means UP, **90** means DOWN, **180** means LEFT).

So here's how you can recognize diagonal swipes:

```js
var hammertime = new Hammer(domElement);
hammertime.get("swipe").set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
hammertime.on("swipe", function(eventObject) {
    if(eventObject.angle < -90) {
        //UP-LEFT SWIPE...
    } else if(eventObject.angle < 0) {
        //UP-RIGHT SWIPE...
    } else if(eventObject.angle < 90) {
        //DOWN-RIGHT SWIPE...
    } else {
        //DOWN-LEFT SWIPE...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want an 8 way swipe *(up, down, left, right, up-left, down-left, up-right, down--right)* option using HammerJS. it's worth looking into using the angle in a range of values. The left option is the only clever one... since it's an OR statement rather than an AND statement.

```
    var hammertime = new Hammer(domElement);
    hammertime.get("swipe").set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
    hammertime.on("swipe", function(e) {

      let jResult = '';

      switch(true) {

            // LEFT
            case (e.angle < -157.5 || e.angle > 157.5):
                jResult = 'left'; 
                break;

            // RIGHT
            case (e.angle > -22.5 && e.angle < 22.5):
                jResult = 'right'; 
                break;

            // UP
            case (e.angle < -67.5 && e.angle > -112.5):
                jResult = 'up'; 
                break;

            // Down
            case (e.angle > 67.5 && e.angle < 112.5):
                jResult = 'down'; 
                break;

            // LEFT-Up
            case (e.angle < -112.5 && e.angle > -157.5):
                jResult = 'left-Up'; 
                break;

            // LEFT-Down
            case (e.angle > 112.5 && e.angle < 157.5):
                jResult = 'left-Down'; 
                break;

            // RIGHT-Up
            case (-22.5 > e.angle && e.angle > -67.5):
                jResult = 'right-Up'; 
                break;

            // RIGHT-Down
            case (e.angle > 22.5 && e.angle < 67.5):
                jResult = 'right-Down'; 
                break;

            default:
                // code block
                jResult = 'unknown'; // UNKNOWN - what happened?
            }
        console.log('--00--> Swipe: ' + e.direction + ' -- Dir is: ' + jResult);
        this.lastSwipe = jResult;  
    });
```

Output is shown to console... your milage may vary.